# Find the solution set for $[\sin^{-1}x]>[\cos^{-1}x]$, where $[.]$ is greatest integer function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The values of $[\sin^{-1}x] \in [-2,1]$ and $[\cos^{-1}x] \in [0,3]$

How do i solve it from here? I have no idea on how to go further. I am not able to convert the graphs to GIFs, and I can’t do it algebraically either.

Comment: I agree that you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem but in order to maintain this site as a repository of quality mathematical knowledge you should read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Since $\arccos(x)$ is decreasing while $\arcsin(x)$ is increasing and $\arccos(\sqrt{2}/2)=\arcsin(\sqrt{2}/2) = \frac{\pi}{4}<1$ the problem reduces to finding $\arcsin(x)=1$ no?

Comment: If you make graphs without the greatest integer function and think about what values of $y$ get taken where by the greatest integers, you should be able to figure it out.  You either need $\arcsin x=1$ while $\arccos \lt 1$, or $\arcsin x \gt 0, \arccos x \lt 0$

Comment: Analyzing graphically is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\lfloor \sin^{-1}x \rfloor=\begin{cases}1, & \sin 1\le x\le 1 \\ 0,& 0\le x\lt \sin 1 \\ -1,& -\sin 1\le x\lt 0 \\ -2,& -1\le x\lt -\sin 1 \end{cases} $$ and

$$\lfloor \cos^{-1}x \rfloor=\begin{cases} 0, &\cos1\lt x\le 1 \\ \vdots\end{cases} $$ We don't need to worry about the other values, as they will turn out to be $\ge 1$, but $\sin^{-1} x\le 1$. Your inequality will only be true, when $$\lfloor \sin^{-1} x\rfloor =1  \land \lfloor \cos^{-1} x\rfloor =0$$ That is, we need to take the intersection of the range of values for which the two equalities hold. The answer is hence $$[\sin 1,1] \cap (\cos 1, 1]\\=\color{purple}{[\sin 1, 1]} \\ (\because \sin 1\gt \cos 1) $$

Answer (score -1):

Not a complete solution

For $x\le0,[\sin^{-1}x]\le-1$  and $[\cos^{-1}x]>\left[\dfrac\pi2\right]=1$

Clearly we need $[\sin^{-1}x],[\cos^{-1}x]\in [0,1]$

$1=[\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x]\ge[\sin^{-1}x]+[\cos^{-1}x]>2[\cos^{-1}x]$

$\implies [\cos^{-1}x]<\dfrac12$

But $0\le[\cos^{-1}x]\le3\implies[\cos^{-1}x]=0\implies0\le \cos^{-1}x<1\iff x>\cos1\ \ \ \  (1)$

Again  as $[\cos^{-1}]x\ge0,[\sin^{-1}x] $ must be $>0\iff[\sin^{-1}x]\ge1\iff x\ge\sin1\ \ \ \  (2)$

Now $\sin1-\cos1=\sqrt2\sin\left(1-\dfrac\pi4\right)>0,$ so by $(1),(2), x\ge\sin1$ which is obviously a necessary condition

I am trying to find the sufficient condition.